# How to set Max Login Failures in keyCloak client?

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-rest-api

I'm using keycloak client version 12.0.0. Can anyone guide me how to set Max Login Failures for keycloak programmatically ? I cannot not find it anywhere in Keycloak document.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

`Max Login Failures` (`failureFactor`) is not a configuration on the client level, but on the realm level. It must be PUT request, such as:

```
curl -X PUT \
  <AUTHENTICATION> \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8' \
  -d '{"id":"<REALM>", ..., "failureFactor":30, ....}' \
  'https://<KEYCLOAK_DOMAIN>/auth/admin/realms/<REALM>'
```